# How to put a white line between two calls to Console.WriteLine()?

Tags: c#

In my code I have:

```
Console.WriteLine("Flight Computer");
Console.WriteLine("Enter an Airport Code");
```

my output is currently:

> Flight Computer
>  Enter an Airport Code

I want there to be a white line between the 2 lines like this:

> Flight Computer
>
> Enter an Airport Code

Not sure how to fix it, I've been trying `Console.Write` and `Console.Read` but no luck. How can I add a white line?

Comment: Console.WriteLine();

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Flight Computer\n\nEnter an Airport Code");`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

2 ways to do it:

**First:**

```
Console.WriteLine("Flight Computer\n");
Console.WriteLine("Enter an Airport Code");
```

add a `\n` at the end of first line

**Second:**

```
Console.WriteLine("Flight Computer");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter an Airport Code");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.WriteLine("Flight Computer" + "\n" + "Enter an Airport Code");
```

Another way not so different but introduce the concept of concatenation. `"+"` works to `join` the two `strings`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Environment.NewLine`.

MSDN says it is

> A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing "\n" for Unix platforms.

*Small refactoring suggestion of your code:*
Make a function and let parameters decide about `newline`.

```
private void WriteToConsole(string message, bool insertNewlineBefore)
{
    if(insertNewLineBefore)
    {
         Console.Write(System.Environment.NewLine);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

And call it like

```
WriteToConsole("Flight Computer");
WriteToConsole("Enter an Airport Code", true);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Console.WriteLine("hello" + "\n"+"\n"+ "world");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your question to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post. Besides, how is this any different than answers as old as 4,5 years already present on this question?